# Using an IoC container with Xamarin Forms 4.0 Shell to resolve page instances

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, ioc-container, xamarin.forms.shell

I am currently attempting to migrate a current Xamarin Forms 2.0 application to make use of the new Xamarin Shell facilities (in particular the navigation).  This existing application is based on a MVP pattern which means that in my Presenter layer i inject instances of my pages to allow the presenter to wire up events on the pages.

I am struggling at the moment in achieving this this Shell as from what I understand it is in control of creating instances of the pages and does not use the IoC I am currently using (which happens to be Unity).

Is there a way that I can configure the Shell to use my IoC container to resolve the page instances when it is creating them rather than creating them itself.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: They say that there is nothing around yet, see here https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/issues/469#issuecomment-499820683 ... Did you manage to solve the issue?